# Where to specify REST API parameter for GET method in ADF Web Activity

Tags: azure-data-factory

Lets say we have the following URL

https://management.someurl.com?api-version=2020-06-01

Now I have a list of parameters for the REST API call. The method I am trying to call using the web activity is GET -- so there is no body section there. So where do I exactly specify these parameters? Header is clearly not meant for this purpose as these are specific application level API parameters. In case of POST calls I could successfully specify the parameters in the body section of the web activity.

Comment: hi. Are you talking about query params?

Comment: Hi @Dhiraj, If my answer is helpful for you, please accept(mark) it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to @Raunak Jhawar's answer.
You can define some variables previously, as follows:
[image]

Then you can add dynamic content to the **URL** field.

```
@concat(variables('BaseUrl'),concat(variables('Path'),concat('?productId=',variables('QueryParam'))))
```

[image]

The input shows:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You should create dataset parameters.

In this case, create a base URL parameter which will have the base URL (i.e. the management.someURL.com URL)

Create a relative URL parameter which will have details of the query parameters. Use dynamic expressions in dataset configuration to create this query string.

Alternatively, you can follow [this](https://datasavvy.me/2020/01/30/parameterizing-a-rest-api-linked-service-in-data-factory/) blog to understand the design process.